# Solving a Dataframe question on ZyBooks (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe

## 19.7 Cats Dataframe

In the following, you will be using the `cats` dataframe:

```py
    name = ['zoe','sadie','linus','sophie','heidi', 'tobey','jasper']
    sex = ['female','female','male','female','female','male','male']
    shy = [True, False, True, False, False, False , False]
    meow_volume = [10,10,8,4,12,6,10]
    # 0=unknown, 1=january, 2=februrary, ... and so on
    birth_month = [3,0,6,0,0,9,4]

    cats = pd.DataFrame({
        'name':name,
        'sex':sex,
        'shy':shy,
        'meow_volume':meow_volume,
        'birth_month':birth_month
    })
```

Your task is to implement two functions that retrieve specific quantities from this dataframe.

1. Implement function `get_min_by_sex(df,s,col)` which returns the minimum value of column `col` for cats that are of sex `s`. Note that `col` and `s` are strings and `df` is a pandas dataframe.
2. Implement function `get_mean_by_birth_month(df,gt,col)` which returns the mean value of column `col` for cats with a `birth_month` greater than `gt`. Note that `col` is a string, `gt` is a number, and `df` is a pandas dataframe.

Your implementations will only be tested on columns having integer or floating point values.

Given

```py
import pandas as pd

# returns the minimum value of column col for sex s
def get_min_by_sex(df,s,col):
    pass
# returns the mean of column col for rows with a birth_month > gt
def get_mean_by_birth_month(df,gt,col):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # the data frame stores animal information for a local shelter
    name = ['zoe','sadie','linus','sophie','heidi', 'tobey','jasper']
    sex = ['female','female','male','female','female','male','male']
    shy = [True, False, True, False, False, False , False]
    meow_volume = [10,10,8,4,12,6,10]
    # 0=unknown, 1=january, 2=februrary, ... and so on
    birth_month = [3,0,6,0,0,9,4]
    
    cats = pd.DataFrame({
        'name':name,
        'sex':sex,
        'shy':shy,
        'meow_volume':meow_volume,
        'birth_month':birth_month
    })
    print(get_min_by_sex(cats,'male','meow_volume'))
    print(get_mean_by_birth_month(cats,0,'meow_volume'))
```

I'm just so confused and I don't even know where to start. I think If I could see the answer it would help me understand/prepare for exam.

Answer (score 0):

On Stack you typically have answers flagged to be closed when there's a request to solve a homework problem without an answer attempted. But sure look when you don't know where to start, things are tricky.

So a super quick answer before your question gets closed:

```
# returns the minimum value of column col for sex s
def get_min_by_sex(df,s,col):
    return df[df["sex"]==s][col].min()
    
# returns the mean of column col for rows with a birth_month > gt
def get_mean_by_birth_month(df,gt,col):
    return df[df["birth_month"] > gt][col].mean()
```

Usage:

```
print(get_min_by_sex(cats, 'female', 'meow_volume'))
print(get_mean_by_birth_month(cats, 8, "meow_volume"))
```

**Understanding This:**

The two functions pretty much do the exact same thing. So if you understand the `get_min_by_sex` function, you understand the second one. Breaking it down step by step.

1. First consider this bit right in the very middle: `df["sex"]==s`. This creates a `pd.Series` (basically a column of a `DataFrame`) where each value is either `True` or `False`, depending whether `sex` equals `s`. This is a common pattern in Pandas and it's called a boolean mask.
2. Second, take a look at the bigger bit `df[df["sex"]==s]`. Notice that if the first bit `df["sex"]==s` were just called `A`, then this bigger bit is simply `df[A]`. When you do `df[]`, and put a boolean mask in the square brackets, it returns only those rows corresponding to `True` in the mask, and drops all the rows corresponding to `False`.
3. So `df[df["sex"]==s]` returns the `df` where it only has rows where `sex` is `s`. Great. The next bit, `[col]`, applies to this newly returned df. It pulls out the column whose name is `col`.
4. Finally, the `.min()` gets the smallest value from the column whose name is `col`.

If you broke this all up line by line you could print out each step along the way.

```
boolean_mask = df["sex"]==s
rows_that_match_on_sex = df[boolean_mask]
column_corresponding_to_col = df[col]
min_of_col = column_corresponding_to_col.min()
```